# How do I make a mongodb find where a field(object) includes all properties from my query (names and values)?

Tags: mongodb

Consider my query to be: {cheese:"Cheddar"} and I have the following collections:
{vegetable:"Lettuce", cheese:"Cheddar"}, {cheese:"Blue"}, {milk:"Chocolate}, {cheese:"Cheddar"}

How do I make a find that returns me all collections that include cheese:Cheddar?
The result would be {vegetable:"Lettuce", cheese:"Cheddar"}, {cheese:"Cheddar"} but right now it fives me just {cheese:"Cheddar"}. From what I investigated I only found tokens to work with arrays.

I do NOT know the name of the property is cheese, nor do I know if there are any other ingredients.

I am looking for a way to get documents from a collection, where the query is included in a field, by the names of the properties in the query and the respective values.

Comment: When you say collections in the first line, do you mean documents? If you want to find documents from different collections you should do multiple queries.

Answer (score 1):

Using `db.collection.findOne({cheese:"Cheddar"})` you will get as a result only one document, maybe `{cheese:"Cheddar"}` or maybe `{vegetable:"Lettuce", cheese:"Cheddar"}`, the first one that MongoDB finds depending on the _id field. If what you want is getting both, you should use `db.collection.find({cheese:"Cheddar"})`.

Comment: My bad, i copy pasted it wrong, i used find in my code. It returns only one result. I may have oversimplified my example, as the recipes are a property of the collections and I am using find( {ingredients:{cheese:"Cheddar"}}) and you have collections like {_id:0,ingredients:{vegetable:"Lettuce", cheese:"Cheddar"}}. I'm new to this and I will feel embarrassed to see the solution. I understand its trying to return to me an accurate query but I am looking for a partial hit on the find, basically.

Comment: Ok, then in this case, what you should use is `db.collection.find({"ingredients.cheese":"Cheddar"})`

Comment: Right but I don't know its called cheese and might be 2 ingredients. Basically if my query is included by property names and their respective values, return me that collection(s). Would this description spark a solution?

Comment: If your documents have more ingredients than cheese, this will still give you the right result, you should simply be sure that the field that you want is called cheese.

Comment: I am not sure you understand the difference between documents and collections. By the example you are giving you should only have one collection, the collection of reciepies

Comment: you are right gtsouk. Allow me to recap. I am looking for a way to get documents from a collection, where the query is included in a field, by the names of the properties in the query and the respective values.

Comment: excuse me but my question is not answered, the duplicate implies I know the properties' names, which I do not.

Comment: You should know the properties' names in advance to know what you want to get as a result. Why don't you know them?

Comment: I get a json with grocery list and I need all recipes that include those particular ingredients in name and quantity(for each). It would be silly to find() all documents and filter them clientside

Comment: How does your json look like? Do you get from it information about if your ingredient is a vegetable, cheese, etc. or not?

Comment: the ingredient's name is "vegetable" so you know its a vegetable.

Comment: I would advise you to ask a new question explaining this concrete requirement that you have for getting data from a json in a clearer way :)